# Prove that the sum of any two angles of a triangle is less than $180$ degrees without the notion of a parallel line.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

This question is really puzzling me and all the "proofs" which I did were intuitively using the notion of a parallel line somewhere.
I am starting to think that this is impossible but I just want to be absolutely sure.
Please Help!

Comment: Note that not using the parallel postulate means you can't use the fact that a triangle has angle sum $180^\circ$, or any variation on that result, as that simply isn't probable without postulating the existence of these unique parallel lines.

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%A1nos_Bolyai#Career Bolyai became so obsessed with Euclid's parallel postulate that his father, who had pursued the same subject for many years, wrote to him in 1820: "You must not attempt this approach to parallels. I know this way to the very end. I have traversed this bottomless night, which extinguished all light and joy in my life. I entreat you, leave the science of parallels alone...Learn from my example."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** *This proof is from Theorem 1, Corollary 2 in the [lecture notes](http://sites.millersville.edu/rumble/math.353/angle_sum.pdf) mentioned in Reference 1.*

**Transcription of key arguments below:**

The angle sum of a triangle depends on the choice of Parallel Postulate and, given such a choice, is always less than, equal to, or greater than $180◦$.

On the other hand, if we only assume Euclid’s first four postulates, along with the axioms of incidence, congruence, continuity and betweenness, the angle sum of a triangle is always less than or equal to 180◦. This geometry is called neutral (or absolute) geometry.

**Theorem 1** *(Exterior Angle Inequality) The measure of an exterior angle of a triangle is greater than the measure of either remote interior angle*

**Proof.** Given $\triangle ABC$, extend side $BC$ to ray $\overrightarrow {BC}$ and choose a point $D$ on this ray so that $B − C − D$.

***Claim:*** $m∠ACD > m∠A$ and $m∠ACD > m∠B$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AC$ and extend the median $BM$ so that $M$ is the midpoint of $BE$.

[image]

Then $∠AMB$ and $∠CME$ are congruent vertical angles and $\triangle AMB \cong \triangle CME$ by *SAS*. Consequently, $m∠ACE = m∠CAB$ by *CPCTC*. Now, $E$ lies in the half-plane of $A$ and $\overleftrightarrow {CD}$ since $A$ and $E$ are on the same side of $\overleftrightarrow {CD}$. Also, $E$ lies in the half-plane of $D$ and $\overleftrightarrow {AC}$ since $D$ and $E$ are on the same side of $\overleftrightarrow {AC}$. Therefore $E$ lies in the interior of $∠ACD$, which is the intersection of these two half-planes. Finally, $m∠ACD = m∠ACE + m∠ECD > m∠ACE = m∠CAB = m∠A$. The proof that $m∠ACD > m∠B$ is similar.

**Corollary 2** *The sum of the measures of any two interior angles of a triangle is less than $180◦$*.

**Proof.** Given $\triangle ABC$, extend side $B$C to $\overleftrightarrow {BC}$ and choose points $E$ and $D$ on $\overleftrightarrow {BC}$ so that $E −B −C − D$ as given in figure below:

[image]

By *Theorem 1*, $m∠A<m∠ACD, m∠B<m∠ACD$, and $m∠A<m∠ABE$. By adding $m∠C = m∠ACB$
to both sides of the first two inequalities, and by adding $m∠B = m∠ABC$ to both sides of the third we obtain
$$m∠A + m∠C<m∠ACD + m∠ACB = 180◦$$

$$m∠B + m∠C<m∠ACD + m∠ACB = 180◦$$

$$m∠A + m∠B<m∠ABE + m∠ABC = 180◦$$

Hence the proof.

**References:**

1: *, [Lecture Notes](http://sites.millersville.edu/rumble/math.353/angle_sum.pdf) from MATH 353-Survey of Geometry, Millersville University. Fall 2007.

2: Marvin Greenberg, “Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometries:
Development and History,” 3rd Ed., W.H. Freeman and Co., New York, 1993.

Comment: This answer is entirely dependent on an external link for its substance. For posterity, say in case Millersville University moves or removes the PDF, or in case their site is down (temporarily or not), so that the link becomes useless, would you please consider transcibing the proof, or at least the main ideas of the proof in your actual answer post?

Comment: @Arthur: valid point. I'll transcribe it in the next day or two.

Comment: @Arthur: As requested, transcription of proof complete.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand the meaning of "*Notion of parallel lines...*" though I had a thought:

Since the sum of the angles, (say $\angle A,\angle B, \angle C$) of a triangle is $180^\circ$ so the sum of any two angles will be $180^\circ - $the third angle $<180^\circ$. Isn't that sufficient? Or did I missed something?

Comment: No actually when you say that the sum of three angles of a triangle is $180$ we use parallel lines there for the proof of this fact.

Comment: Your answer seems reasonable.  Yet, meta-cheating, I question its legitimacy.  I am **totally ignorant** of Euclid's elements (et al), but your approach seems to imply that the OP is being asked to prove a tautology.  Is it feasible that your answer represents circular reasoning, re you are using an intermediate result that is preceded by the result that the OP is being asked to prove?

Comment: @user2661923 See please my post. I posted it also for you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Each of the sides is a transversal of the two others. On which side of this transversing will the two other sides meet?

Comment: +1 on (besides your logic) vocabulary.  I was going to leave a 200 word comment that would have worked its way around to the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe you need to use the property that sum of two interior angles of a triangle is equal to the opposite exterior angle.

Consider any $\Delta ABC$. Then,
$$\angle A+\angle B=\angle ACD<180^o,$$
since, $BD$ is a straight line and $\angle ACD<\angle BCD=180^o$.

[image]

Comment: We are again assuming the parallel postulate as the exterior angle theorem uses the fact that the sum of angles in a triangle is $180$ and that is derived from the parallel postulate.

Comment: @ShaunakApte ah I understand what you mean

Comment: Ya... Do you feel it is possible?

Comment: @ShaunakApte why not try [Sujit's Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3873214/562589) and prove the $180^o$ sum of angles thing using [Michael's Proof'](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3873224/562589)?

Comment: @ShaunakApte If you don't (somehow) assume the parallel postulate, then the hypothesis is simply false because we're in the realm of non-Euclidean geometry. In [spherical geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_geometry), the angle sum of a triangle is proportional to its area, and is between 180⁰ and 540⁰, so we can easily construct a triangle on a sphere with two angles summing to more than 180⁰. In fact, 3 points on a great circle form a maximal triangle, with each angle equal to 180⁰.

Comment: Sorry, I should've said the area is proportional to the [angle excess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Area_and_spherical_excess), i.e. the angle sum - 180⁰.

Answer (score 0):

If we'll assume that for any triangle a sum of three measured angles is equal to $x$, we can get the following.

Let $D\in AC$ for $\Delta ABC$.

[image]

Thus, $$2x=(\measuredangle ABD+\measuredangle BDA+\measuredangle BAD)+(\measuredangle DBC+\measuredangle BCD+\measuredangle BDC)=$$
$$=x+\measuredangle BDA+\measuredangle BDC=x+180^{\circ},$$
which gives $$x=180^{\circ}.$$
But we can not assume it. We need an axioma of parallels for the right proof.

Comment: "But we can not assume it...."  Does this mean that Arthur's proof is **both** valid **and** the *intended* proof?

Comment: @user2661923 didn't exactly understand Arthur's proof. Could you please explain it?

Comment: @user2661923    The Arthor's proof uses a parallelism. It's not that topic starter looks for.

Comment: @zaira Based on Michael Rozenberg's last comment, this line of thought is **iffy**.  Good thing that I was only going to express it as a comment.  Anyway this is what I would have said: Suppose that two points of the triangle are (0,0) and (1,0).  Further suppose that the 3rd point of the triangle is somewhere on a circle, centered at (0,0), of radius R, where R can be < 1, = 1, or > 1.  The only points on the circle that can't be used to form the triangle are the two points where the circle intersects the X-axis.  ...see next comment

Comment: @zaira Assume that the 3rd point is in the upper half plane, and that angles are going to be
measured by going around the arc of a circle in a counter clockwise direction.  It seems to
me that the angles formed at (0,0) and (1,0) would collectively sum to < 180 degrees.  However,
for all I know, Michael Rozenberg's objection to Arthur's proof also pertains to mine.

Comment: @user2661923 makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @Zaira Yes, but so did Arthur's answer, which Michael Rozenberg objected to.  No way, can I convert my comments into an answer unless I first form an opinion on whether the analysis is **valid**.  No way can I do that, given my ignorance of this area of math.